# How do you change the Minor diameter of a torus in Blender 2.80?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to change the diameter of a torus in Blender 2.80.
The Blender series on this is using Blender 2.79.
How do I do this using Blender 2.80?

Answer (score 4):

When you create your primitive you have a folded menu on the bottom of your 3D View, just unfold it to have access to all the parameters. Once you've made some changes, like moving or editing, you won't have access to this menu anymore though.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Confirming that once you moved it you cannot access the creation parameter, if you actually want to change later the *minor* radius you can simply go in edit face mode, select all the faces and then use the *shrink/fatten* (in the toolbar - bottom left)

[image]